# What is the purpose of the cbSize member in Win32API structs

Tags: c++, winapi, api

I frequently encounter some definitions for Win32API structures (but not limited to it) that have a `cbSize` member as in the following example.

```
typedef struct _TEST {
    int cbSize;
    // other members follow
} TEST, *PTEST;
```

And then we use it like this:

```
TEST t = { sizeof(TEST) };
...
```

or

```
TEST t;
t.cbSize = sizeof(TEST);
...
```

My initial guess is that this could potentially be used for versioning. A DLL that receives a pointer for a struct like this can check if the `cbSize` member has the expected value with which the DLL was compiled. Or to check if proper packing is done for the struct. But I would like to here from you.

**What is the purpose of the `cbSize` member in some C++ structures on Win32API?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> My initial guess is that this could
>   potentially be used for versioning.

That's one reason.  I think it's the more usual one.

Another is for structures that have variable length data.

I don't think that checking for correct packing or bugs in the caller are a particular reasoning behind it, but it would have that effect.

Answer (score 13):

It is used for versioning.  A good example is the [GetVersionEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724451(VS.85).aspx) call.  You can pass in either an [OSVERSIONINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724834(VS.85).aspx) or [OSVERSIONINFOEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724833(VS.85).aspx).  The OSVERSIONINFOEX is a superset of OSVERSIONINFO, and the only way the OS knows which you have passed in is by the dwOSVersionInfoSize member.

Comment: Stucts vary in size between OS versions as well. I just hit a bug using the platform sdk that comes with VC++ 2008. We were not correctly defining the OS version and ended up using the Vista version of a struct - which didn't work so well on my XP box.

Answer (score 3):

It also lets the **WIN32 API** do a minimal amount of sanity checking on the data being passed in.

For example a commom mistake is for a **WIN32** structure to be passed in with an *incorrect* or *uninitialised* **cbSize** and when this happens the **WIN32 API** usually just returns a failed result, rather than try to process what appears to be corrupted data.

Answer (score 1):

Partially versioning, mostly safety... to prevent the called function from poking into memory that wasn't part of the struct passed in.