# Trying to understand structure sizes in the Windows API

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm looking for building an application using the Windows API.
I'm using Go, which can used to interact with the Windows API (by using the `syscall` package), however, that's unimportant for this question.

I'm looking at the API to register a new Sync Root, and that's done using the function [`CfRegisterSyncRoot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfregistersyncroot).

According to this method's signature, it accepts an [`CF_SYNC_REGISTRATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/ns-cfapi-cf_sync_registration) but here I find some information which confuses me.

According to the definition, this function has a field named `StructSize` which represents the size of the structure, but I don't find any more information regarding this.
What am I supposed to pass in here?

Comment: It's often called "cbSize" in many other parts of the Windows API: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189622/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-cbsize-member-in-win32api-structs

Comment: You might want to ask a language specific question. Go probably has a method for finding structure size which matches C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation you linked to says the `StructSize` member is the "The size of the structure.".  That means it is the number of bytes used to store the structure in memory.  You can get the right value by evaluating `sizeof(CF_SYNC_REGISTRATION)` in a C compiler, and you should write this value into the `StructSize` member before you pass it to a Windows API function.

This kind of thing is common in the Windows API.  I think this is a mechanism that allows Windows to occasionally add new members to their structs, without breaking compatibility with old code that doesn't know about the new members.

Comment: If you look at [Win32 Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types), you can work out the byte sizes of the individual members of the struct. However, [the Win32 API uses an 8-byte alignment](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090422-00/?p=18493), so Win32 structs often include alignment padding between their fields, which you would have to include in the `StructSize` value (see [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/)).